# Install and run Be OS

Tags: virtual-machine, operating-systems, beos

Just for the sake of fun, I want to download and install [Be OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beos) and install it inside a VirtualBox. Any ideas where I can get it. It would be also great if I can find the R5.1 ("Dano") release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [haiku](http://haiku-os.org/)

It's an open source operating system compatible with BeOS.

Comment: BeOS was cool back in the day... It had some features that I wish modern OSs had.  I actually DLed haiku recently, havent actually tried it tho.

Comment: Haiku isn't actually a fork of the BeOS source.  It's an Open Source binary and source-code compatible clone, much as Linux is independently developed from UNIX and will run UNIX programs with a recompile.

Comment: @Don oh, sorry, BeOS was closed source, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

BeOS 5 Pro CDs can be had from eBay for about eight bucks.  You can also try BeOS personal edition, which must be installed on top of Windows or Linux.  That can be freely downloaded, but sorry I don't have a link.

Comment: I vaguely recall bebits had it , but there was some trickery needed to get it to boot, something about an IDE specific boot disk of some sort.